# Create a Python function that replaces values of a column with values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, function, replace

I am trying to create a function in Python that I can use every time I want to create a new column in a dataframe based on the values of another column. So, I would like to make it as generic as possible.

For example, I have the following dataframe sample with only one column:

[image]

I create a new column called 'image_1' based on the values of 'D2_1 by using the following script:

```
old_value=[1,2]
new_value=[5,3]
dix={k: v for k, v in zip(old_value, new_value)}
test['image_1']=test['D2_1']
test.loc[~test['D2_1'].isin(old_value), 'image_1'] = 0
test=test.replace({'image_1': dix})
```

This script works to find and the new dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Then, I tried to make a generic function based on the above script. My function is the following:

```
def create_column(existing_column,new_column,dataset,old_value,new_value):
    dataset[new_column]=dataset[existing_column]
    dataset.loc[~dataset[existing_column].isin(old_value), new_column] = 0
    dix={k: v for k, v in zip(old_value, new_value)}
    dataset=dataset.replace({column: dix})
```

The function works fine until this line: dix={k: v for k, v in zip(old_value, new_value)}. But does not replace the values of the new column based on dix. Could anyone please help me to understand why?

Comment: add ``return dataset`` at the end.

Comment: what is `column`?

Comment: what does your debugger tells?

Comment: @sushanth thanks this works. The function returns the dataset as I want. How can I make the function to save this new dataset and not return it?

Comment: @jamesoh sorry there was a small mistake in the code. instead of 'column' I should have  'new_column'

Comment: @Cyber-Tech I don't receive an error. the function works but not as I want.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The question is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replace()`

```
df["image_1"] = df["D1_1"].replace({1:5,2:3})
```

Output:

```
    D1_1  image_1

0   1     5
1   1     5
2   1     5
3   3     3
...
11  2     5
12  2     5
```

if you want it as a function:

```
def create_column(existing_column,new_column,dataset,old_new_dict):
    dataset[new_column] = dataset[existing_colum].replace(old_new_dict)  
    return dataset
```